# Simplest way to get InnerHtml WITH current input values?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I'm working on an ASPX web form where each "form" is an HTML literal originally generated in a CKEditor textbox. The HTML is stored as a string and then plugged into the DIV via server-side during the initial page load.

Each form is custom-made. So it could be anything: 20 text boxes in a row, 5 text boxes and 10 radios, all text, etc. I'm sticking to just the basic input controls: Text, Checkbox, Radio, and DropDownList.

What I'm TRYING to do is save the markup code with whatever the user has filled into the form. Once they click a Save button, I want to replace all of the form's default input values with whatever the user currently has typed in/selected/checked/etc. This information will become read-only after the first Save. All the user will be able to do after that is review the information they've already entered and Print the form.

Client-side is running a hodgepodge of ASP.Net, Javascript, and Jquery. Server-side is all C#.

Current problem: All  controls are working correctly after PageLoad. But when I go to retrieve  the DIV on server-side, I'm only getting the original HTML with only the default values filled in (empty string for text box, unchecked for checkbox, etc). I'm tried a couple different ways in JQuery to procedurally loop through each input control it finds and "force" it to overwrite the default value with the current entered value, and THEN passing the updated HTML to server-side, but I'm having no luck there. It really, really wants to keep those default values.

What is the most straightforward solution for something like this? Am I even trying to go about this in the right direction? Should I be trying to capture the DIV's contents as some kind of image instead? (That was my Senior's first suggestion, but neither of us can figure out exactly how to go about it.)

What I DON'T want to do is give all users full access to the CKEditor.

Comment: It not clear here, but we assume some system admin or webmaster built those templates using ckEditor. You present some text boxes etc. for user to fill out. They then I suppose hit submit, and then you load that template, replace all the "fields" in that template - you make up some kind of field such as [email], [FirstName] etc. in that template. Your code then takes user input, replaces above with actual text they typed in, and then you display the results. A standard multi-line text box, with enabled = false should easy render and display the results, should it not?

Comment: If you are suggesting that the user is entering data into text boxes created by ckEditor, then that's going to be difficult, since the markup needs those runat=server tags, and as a general rule, such markup needs to be created at design time - not runtime. but, if the user is to enter things like say firstname, quote amounts etc? Then that input information is fixed and known. You can then take that user input and replace input values in that template, and then display template results in a text box. does the div have a runat=server?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal  The control is divApprovalText and it's set to runat=server. It can be rendered as either an ASP:Literal or HtmlGenericControl (I've been experimenting back and forth both ways). The HTML for the form gets loaded in as divApprovalText.InnerHtml (Generic Control) or divApprovalText.Text (ASP:Literal). All of the controls are very basic input="checkbox", input="text", etc. I know from previous projects trying to plug in server-side ASP controls into the text itself will never work, but basic inputs are rendering correctly... (cont.)

Comment: ...(Part 2) The problem is when I pull the divApprovalText control again at the Save method, the server only gets the HTML layout from my PageLoad with all the input values blank/default. Is there a way I get text box changes, radio button clicks, etc. to reflect in the HTML itself so when I store the HTML string, it includes whatever the user entered?